# ARKit + SceneKit: Can I access the frame's segmentationBuffer but disable automatic person occlusion?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm using ARKit plus SceneKit and would like to apply custom rendering to people detected in the frame. To do this, I would like to use the [`ARFrame.segmentationBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2984226-segmentationbuffer)

I can access this buffer if I add [`.personSegmentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/framesemantics/3089125-personsegmentation/) to my ARConfiguration's frame semantics. However this also automatically starts occluding any people in the frame, which prevents my custom rendering from showing up

Is it possible to access the segmentation buffer but disable the automatic person occlusion so I can render people my own way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! With SceneKit, it appears that adding `.personSegmentation` to the frame semantics automatically also adds a `SCNTechnique` that implements person occlusion

To disable this automatic occlusion, simply null out `sceneView.technique`:

```swift
self.sceneView.technique = nil
```

You'll still be able to access the `segmentationBuffer` but the occlusion will no longer be applied

You can also generate a higher resolution matte for detected people using [`ARMatteGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armattegenerator/)